# Determine if cisco phone is on POE or adapter remotely

Tags: cisco, power-over-ethernet, cisco-voip

I'm looking to find out if there is a way to know if a Cisco phone (7940,7960,7911's and the like) either through Cisco Callmanager or through the direct Web interface on the phone.

I'm looking for this so that I can go to all of the switches that we just replaced with PoE switches and go reclaim all the extraneous phone PSUs.

Comment: Do you have access to the switches? if so you can use a combination of CDP form the phones web page to find the neighbor interface, and then "show power inline" from the switch its connected to. maybe not the fastest approach but I cant think of a way currently through call manager or the phones web page

Comment: Yes, I do have access to the switches

Comment: Is the show power inline command suitable to what you are asking?

Comment: *sigh* wandering the internet looking for a solution, finding the exact problem you're wanting to know the answer to!, noticing there's no answer.... noticing it's your question when it says that you can't upvote your own question >.>